# Get different Checkbox options for Dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

The page consists of 2 dropdowns and one checkbox.

The checkbox options in Q03 should depend according to the user selections in Q01 and Q02.

As an instance, if the user selects "shower" in the Q01 and "Burke" as the design in the Q02.

In that case, Q03 should be a single specific checkbox value.

**Code**

```
<html>
A) What are you building?
<br />
<select id="build"> 
<option value="Change">Change Rooms</option>
 <option id="showers" value="showers ">showers </option>  
<option id="Toilets " value="Toilets ">Toilets</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<br />
B) Choose your design:
<br />
<select id="design">
<option  hidden>Choose the Design</option>
<option id="Burke" value="Burke">The Burke</option>
<option value="Burke">The Sturt</option>
<option value="Wentworth">The Wentworth</option>

</select>
<br/>

C) Choose your material


<div id="append_checkbox">
</div>
</html>
<script>


jQuery(function() {
        jQuery('#build').on('change', function() {
                 var slct = jQuery(this).prop("selectedIndex");
                 var amount = jQuery('#build').val();

//alert(amount);


                 if(slct == 1 && amount=='showers')
                     {

                       $("#append_checkbox").html('<input type="checkbox" name="designs[]" value="13mm Compact Laminate only"/>13mm Compact Laminate only');
                      }
                  else if (slct == 2 && amount=='showers')
                      {
                      $("#append_checkbox").html('<input type="checkbox" name="designs[]" value="13mm Compact Laminate only"/>James Hardie Fibre Cement only');
                      }

        });
});
</script>
```

Even there are no console errors when it runs via the browser the expected result won't be shown.

It is expected to get different checkboxes in those 2 instances.

Comment: So do you include jQuery script tag? Is there really no body tag?

Comment: Why are you using selected Index and value in the if? Makes not sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have manythings going wrong here,

1. `value="showers "` should be `value="showers"` (without space)
2. You should not use index as the the check

Take a look at this code, I have added one condition you can add other as per your requirement.

```js
$('#build,#design').on('change', function() {

    var amount = $('#build').val();
    var designVal = $('#design').val();

    //alert(amount);


    if (amount == 'showers' && designVal == 'Burke') {

        $("#append_checkbox").html('<input type="checkbox" name="designs[]" value="13mm Compact Laminate only"/>13mm Compact Laminate only');
    }
    //your other conditions

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A) What are you building?
<br />
<select id="build"> 
<option value="Change">Change Rooms</option>
 <option id="showers" value="showers">showers </option>  
<option id="Toilets " value="Toilets">Toilets</option>
<option value="All">All</option>
</select>

<br />
B) Choose your design:
<br />
<select id="design">
<option  hidden>Choose the Design</option>
<option id="Burke" value="Burke">The Burke</option>
<option value="Burke">The Sturt</option>
<option value="Wentworth">The Wentworth</option>

</select>
<br/>

C) Choose your material


<div id="append_checkbox">
</div>
```